# PHP read CSV file line by line

Tags: php, loops, csv

I have a CSV file contains a list of URLs that I want to download images. So the question is how to read CSV file line by line and run my code on each of URL.

I have links.csv file

```
url1.com
url2.com
url3.com
```

Here is my code that I want to run

```
$results_page = curl($url);

$img_url = scrape_between($results_page, "\"mainUrl\":\"", "\",\"dimensions\"");

$title = scrape_between($results_page, "<span id=\"productTitle\" class=\"a-size-large\">", "</span>"); 
$find = array('/ /', '/:/');
$replace = array('_', '');
$img_name = preg_replace($find, $replace, $title);

$data = curl($img_url);
file_put_contents('images/'.$img_name.'.jpg', $data);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Suggestion: search for "csv" in the PHP manual

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783269/how-to-save-data-from-csv-file-to-database-using-php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$fileData=fopen($file,'r');

while($row=fgets($fileData)){  
    // can parse further $row by usingstr_getcsv
    echo $row."\n";
   }
```

Comment: How about `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: fgetcsv parse csv line, returns comma separated values as array, but @user3058657 wanted to read full line.

Comment: And close the file `fclose($fileData);` after the loop